# How does Secure Boot handle keys?

Tags: secure-boot

I have been trying to understand how Secure Boot works, but there is still something not clear to me, which is the reason behind this post.

This is what I understood so far.

Secure Boot is a system, defined in the UEFI standard, which uses digital signatures to prevent malicious OS images/bootloaders from launching.

Secure Boot uses 4 different kinds of signatures/certificates:

- Platform Key: to check that the UEFI firmware is trusted
- Key Exchange Key: to verify updates on the key databases (but I do not know how)
- Whitelist and Blacklist keys databases: contain trusted and not trusted signatures/certificates

The verification process works as follows:

The pre-bootloader (shim) verifies the bootloader by computing its signature and verifying it with the certificates in the database; if it is ok, the bootloader starts.

The same happens for the OS image, which is verified by the bootloader in the same manner. If checks pass, the OS can start.

Is everything correct so far?

Now, what it is not clear to me yet:

- When are certificates/signatures added to the DB? Let us suppose I want to configure a dual boot system, when are the keys of the second OS declared? At installation time? If so, I need to authorize an external OS image to modify the databases... it is not so secure, isn't it?
- How can the DB be updated? How is the Key Exchange Key (KEK) used?

Comment: I do not see this as a problem related to Ubuntu. Heck the whole "secure boot" idea is a Microsoft concept we ignored/disabled on the Linux end. See for instance this doc from MS:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-secure-boot-key-creation-and-management-guidance?view=windows-11

Comment: Ubuntu has a specific procedure for handling generation of keys and signing.  A quick search didn't find the default location of those keys or I would have added that to my answer for manually enrolling a key.  I've done it before, the location is ubuntu specific, and different distros move it around.

Comment: This is Ubuntu specific in the sense that Canonical does get their boot binaries signed for secure boot.

Comment: @Rinzwind. Yes, I know that the whole idea of Secure Boot comes from Windows, but I have posted the question here because I know that there are Linux distros which are compliant with Secure boot

Comment: @user10489, so can I say that Canonical signs their boot binaries and insert their key in the database, in a specific location for Linux distros?

Comment: What database?  There is no database.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the memory where keys are stored for Secure Boot

Comment: Canonical colludes with Microsoft, either getting Microsoft to sign their key or sign their binaries.  (I haven't checked which.)

Answer (score 2):

Keys are not "declared", they are installed (aka "enrolled").  Binaries are signed so that they can be verified by a key.  The key is associated with an authority, not with a binary.  Many binaries can be signed by a single key, and there can be chains of keys.

Typically, the binary is signed by a distributor like Microsoft or Canonical.  This fits the description of almost the entire boot chain.

Sometimes when binaries are built locally (like with a DKMS device driver), they have to be signed with a local key.  In this case, part of installing the driver involves enrolling the local key.  Half of this is done when the driver is installed (it may ask you to enter a password), and the other half is done on next machine reboot (when it asks you to re-enter that password).

If the process of enrolling the local key fails, the driver will not load.  You can fix this by either manually enrolling the key, or rerunning the configuration with `dpkg-reconfigure drivername...` and then redoing the password/enrollment process.

Comment: "Half of this is done when the driver is installed [...], and the other half is done on next machine reboot". This once happened to me when I tried to configure Ubuntu in a dual boot system. Is this kind of password a MOK?

Comment: Yes>  MOK = Machine Owner's Key.  The DKMS driver is what triggers this typically.  Not sure, but I think you only have to do this once and then all future drivers can share the same key.